# Do $L^p$ spaces have the approximation property?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, compact-operators

A Banach space $X$ has the approximation property if every compact operator $T:X \to X$ is the norm-limit of a sequence of finite-rank operators.

My question is if there is a simple proof that the approximation property holds for $L^p(\Sigma,\mu)$ spaces. It would be enough for me to prove this property in the case that $T$ is linear.

I have found a proof of this in the case $\mu(\Sigma)<\infty$ in which the sequence is explicitely found but I am unable to adapt the proof for the general case.

Any reference would be appreciated too. Thanks

Comment: If possible, I would like to know where you found the proof for finite measure spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Norbert answered your question but it seems to me that there is no need for such a machinery here.

First, note that if the measure $\mu$ is infinite but $\sigma$-finite, using [the Radon–Nikodym theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem), you can find an isometry between $L_p(\mu)$ and $L_p(\nu)$ for some finite measure $\nu$.

Let $p\in [1,\infty)$. Now, suppose that $\mu$ is arbitrary. It is enough to show that each separable subspace of $L_p(\mu)$ is contained in a complemented (separable) subspace with the approximation property. Let $X\subset L_p(\mu)$ be separable. Let $Y$ be the sublattice generated by $X$; clearly $Y$ is separable too. By the Kakutani theorem, $Y$ is complemented and isometric to $L_p(\nu)$ for some $\sigma$-finite measure $\nu$ in which case $Y$ has the approximation property.

For $p=\infty$ consider the pointwise-closed subalgebra generated by $X$.

Comment: Dear Tomek, I would be very happy if you could point me to a source where it is shown that $L^p (\mu) $ for finite $\mu $ has the approximation property :)

Comment: @PhoemueX, this is folk knowledge and does not require $\mu$ to be finite. It follows from the fact that $X$ has AP whenever every separable subspace of $X$ is contained in a separable, complemented subspace with AP (this is because norm-compact sets are norm-separable). Then, given $Y\subseteq L_p(\mu)$, take the closed lattice generated by $Y$. By the Kakutani theorem, it must be either $\ell_p$ or $L_p$ so in either case it has (M)AP.

Comment: Ha, I haven't read my answer so I rewrote here it once again :-) As for a reference, try Wojtaszczyk's Banach spaces for analysts.

Answer (score 1):

Not even every $L_p$ space for $1\leq p\leq\infty$ have the approximation property, but every $\mathfrak{L}_p^g$ have bounded approximation property. For details see section 23.3 in [Tensor Norms and Operator Ideals. A. Defant, K. Floret](http://bookfi.org/book/1113022)